# Displaying large VRML file

Tags: rendering, vrml, triangle-count, bigdata

I've VRML file that is 4.2GB big (!) and consists of 10 different shapes.
This is cloud of points (no edges or triangles).

How can I display such a big object? Everything I've tried just freezes.
Is there any tool I can use for point optimization in stream-like fashion?
Without loading the whole file?

Answer (score 0):

We have developed our own tool for polygon reduction and some other optimizations. But if you say you have cloud of points and no triangles and edges, it is a difficult case.
I would try to make a separate VRML file from each shape of yours, and combine them with `Inline` in a big container VRML file. You may not see the whole scene, but you can possibly see the separate shapes. You can find tutorials for `Inline` if you google it. Hope this helps.